removing section heading from reference pages
The last section heading is appearing on all reference pages in my project. I tried \section* but the problem is not going away. How do I take this out?
\section*{Areas of further study}

\begin{itemize}
\item[$\bullet$] A lot of researchers have tried using other statistical techniques to solve the mystery behind poor mathematics performance globally but little has been done using multivariate techniques like Correspondence Analysis (CA), Multiple Correspondence Analysis (MCA) etc.
\item[$\bullet$] A study on the effect of geographical location on students' math performance can be re-conducted in the Limpopo province with all 7 public TVET colleges and some private TVET colleges involve.
\end{itemize} 

This is the last section of my project. I do not want Areas of further study appearing as a header on my reference pages.

Welcome to TeX SE. Could you add a minimal working example to show what you mean and what you want?

\markboth{}{} should do it.  You can also set \rightmark and \leftmark directly.

There are other related questions like Non numbered chapter* header issue (note, that \section* is similar to \chapter* and the answer also gives an answer for \section*) or Want \section* to change the page header BTW: The shown code is still not a working example (see the link in Alain's comment). So we, e.g., don't know the used class and therefore if there are better alternatives.

Thanks John. \markboth{}{} did the magic for me
